# USB mouse stops working after a few seconds of inactivity.

Tags: windows-10, wireless-mouse

I've had this mouse for about a year, and it has been working great until recently. Upon going onto my computer today, I began using my mouse, and typed something, leaving it idle for several seconds. I then went to move my mouse again, but I noticed that it wouldn't move the cursor when moving, but the lights on the mouse were still on. I turned off the mouse, then back on, and it worked again. Then I began typing, and when I went to move my mouse again, the cursor again didn't move. I switched to a different USB port, checked for driver updates, and reinstalled the driver, but it hasn't changed anything. It only works as long as I'm constantly moving it, and if I leave it idle for several seconds, it'll stop working again until I restart it. The mouse is a 2.4GHz Wireless Optical Mouse, and I'm using Windows 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with checking the battery. My MX Master does this intermittently - I've read that it's a result of being a 2.4ghz mouse, which somehow does not play nice with the 2.4ghs wifi. I don't know if I buy that but I figured I'd mention it.

I'd also try doing a safe boot - see if it works at all at that point.

Comment: Battery is a good bet since it started happening after a year or so of standard usage . . . probably worth checking power saving settings (the mouse or receiver could be going to sleep and not waking back up)

Answer (score 1):

check the laser doesn't have dust or eyelash or whatever obstructing it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your computer might be trying to "optimize" power usage.

Check:

## 1) Powe plan settings:

Settings -> Power & Sleep -> Additional Power Settings (in the advanced section on the right - this opens the Power panel from Control Panel) -> (for the current power plan) Change advanced power settings

See image at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwFib.jpg

On this screen look for various power-saving settings such as:

- Wireless adapter settings -> Power saving mode
- USB Settings -> USB Selective Suspend setting
- PCI Express -> Link State Power Management

## 2) Device settings

Additionally - check Device Manager, open the properties for your mouse and see if you have a Power Management tab. If you do check if the setting "Allow the computer to turn off this device to conserve power" is selected.